# Exploration "on" or "of"

Tags: grammar, differences

As already written in the title, I need help on how to write the following:

> A exploration on Levy alpha-stable distributions

or

> A exploration of Levy alpha-stable distributions

In an other context:

> A exploration on the Poisson distribution

or

> A exploration of the Poisson distribution

Can anyone tell me what the right choice is?

Comment: Typically explorers are known for their explorations _of_ things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could easily find the answer to this question by refering to a dictionary.

[LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com) says:

> **[exploration](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/exploration)** `noun`
>
> 1. the act of travelling through a place in order to find out about it or find something such as oil or gold in it:
>      *oil exploration facilities in the North Sea*
>      *You can then use this hut as a base for explorations into the mountains around.*
>      **exploration of**
>      *the exploration of space*
> 2. when you try to find out more about something by discussing it, thinking about it etc.:
>      **exploration into/of**
>      *an exploration into how an abused child becomes an abuser*
>      *the exploration of literary texts*

So you can easily understand that the correct preposition to be used with the noun *exploration* is *of* or *into*, not <del>*on*</del>.

You must also remember to use the correct indefinite article before a vowel, which is *an*, rather than <del>*a*</del>. Therefore your correct phrases will be:

> **An** exploration **of** Levy alpha-stable distributions

and

> **An** exploration **of** Poisson distributions

Comment: What about [An Exploration on Greenhouse Gas and Ammonia Production by Insect Species Suitable for Animal or Human Consumption](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0014445) published by _Oonincx DGAB, van Itterbeeck J, Heetkamp MJW, van den Brand H, van Loon JJA, et al. (2010)_? I feel your statement **So you can easily understand that the correct preposition to be used with the noun exploration is of or into, not on.** might be true in some or most cases, but not always.

Comment: @ManishGiri Thanks for pointing that out, however, with all the respect to the authors of that paper, I have to mention that they're from Netherlands (at least three of them as I checked), and there is a chance that after composing and proofreading everything carefully, they've had the minor mistake with the choice of preposition, which is quite fine and understandable for a non-native speaker, and we should not rely on that link as a reference to say "Exploration *on*" is correct. We all know that even with native speakers,not everyone is careful with grammar and choice of words all the time.

Comment: Where I think you might get "on" from is expressions like "An essay on Y" or "A treatise on Z".  If you then think of your essay (for example) as "an exploration" then it's *tempting* to say it's "An exploration on Y".  But, "an exploration" doesn't make sense as a standalone noun word: it begs the question "What is being explored?".  So you can't use it like you can "An essay".